# ExactTarget SSJS Bulk Upserting into All Subscribers - Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, landing-page

I have a JSON object containg Subscriber Key, Email Address and some other attributes.

I would like to upsert the All Subscribers with this object, but it seems that Marketing Cloud only upserts the first one, and all subsequent array items aren't processed (Email address and Subscriber Key are null)

```
function massUpsert(subObj, allSubscribers) {
    var statusJSON = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < subObj.length; i++) {
        var email = subObj[i].EmailAddress;
        var Sk = subObj[i].SubscriberKey;
        var BrandCode = subObj[i].BrandCode;
        var SendLanguage = subObj[i].SendLanguage;
        var newSubscriber = {
            "EmailAddress": email,
            "SubscriberKey": Sk,
            "EmailTypePreference": "HTML",
            "Attributes": {
                "BrandCode": BrandCode,
                "SendLanguage": SendLanguage
            },
            "Lists": {
                "Status": "Active",
                "ID": allSubscribers,
                "Action": "Upsert"
            }
        };
        var subObj = Subscriber.Init(Sk);
        upsertStatus = subObj.Upsert(newSubscriber)
        var status = {};
        status["SK"] = Sk;
        status["Email"] = email;
        status["UpsertStatus"] = upsertStatus;
        statusJSON.push(status);
    }
}
```

Reponse:

```
{"UpsertingIntoAllSubs":[{"SK":"16347460029","Email":"email@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, 
    {"SK":null,"Email":null,"UpsertStatus":"Error"}, 
    {"SK":null,"Email":null,"UpsertStatus":"Error"}, 
    {"SK":null,"Email":null,"UpsertStatus":"Error"}, 
    {"SK":null,"Email":null,"UpsertStatus":"Error"}, 
    {"SK":null,"Email":null,"UpsertStatus":"Error"}, 
    {"SK":null,"Email":null,"UpsertStatus":"Error"}, 
    {"SK":null,"Email":null,"UpsertStatus":"Error"}]}
```

When I processed each array item individually, the response is always "OK".

Does some kind of delay need to be implemented between each upsert?
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not just put the `upsert` related code inside the `for` loop?

Comment: Sorry I think the alignment is a bit out, i've edited it again to be clearer :)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your JSON object?

Comment: [
  {
    "subObj": [
      {
        "SubscriberKey": "16347460029",
        "EmailAddress": "email1@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        "SubscriberKey": "345383714258",
        "EmailAddress": "email2@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        "SubscriberKey": "44568799855",
        "EmailAddress": "email3@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        "SubscriberKey": "43658751542",
        "EmailAddress": "email4@gmail.com",
      },
      {
        "SubscriberKey": "77836423975",
        "EmailAddress": "email5@gmail.com",
      }   
    ]
  }
]

Comment: So have you confirmed that `sk` and `email` have values in every iteration of your loop?

Comment: Yes, most definitely :)  When replacing the variable [i] with values 1 - 5 then the upsert works for that item correctly - it's only when running in a loop that the errors occur.  You'll see that there is a  var Sk = subObj[i].SubscriberKey;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redefining `subObj` inside your function.  I renamed `subObj2` in the line that inits the Subscriber Object and everything works:

```
<script language=javascript runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
var allSubscribers = 1103;
var subObj1 = [
  {"SubscriberKey":"16347460029","EmailAddress":"email1@gmail.com"},
  {"SubscriberKey":"345383714258","EmailAddress":"email2@gmail.com"},
  {"SubscriberKey":"44568799855","EmailAddress":"email3@gmail.com"},
  {"SubscriberKey":"43658751542","EmailAddress":"email4@gmail.com"},
  {"SubscriberKey":"77836423975","EmailAddress":"email5@gmail.com"}
];

function massUpsert(subObj, allSubscribers) {

  var statusJSON = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < subObj.length; i++) {

      var email = subObj[i].EmailAddress;
      var Sk = subObj[i].SubscriberKey;
      var BrandCode = subObj[i].BrandCode;
      var SendLanguage = subObj[i].SendLanguage;

      var newSubscriber = {
          "EmailAddress": email,
          "SubscriberKey": Sk,
          "EmailTypePreference": "HTML",
          "Attributes": {
              "BrandCode": BrandCode,
              "SendLanguage": SendLanguage
          },
          "Lists": {
              "Status": "Active",
              "ID": allSubscribers,
              "Action": "Upsert"
          }
      };
      var subObj2 = Subscriber.Init(Sk);
      var upsertStatus = subObj2.Upsert(newSubscriber)
      var status = {};
      status["SubscriberKey"] = Sk;
      status["EmailAddress"] = email;
      status["UpsertStatus"] = upsertStatus;
      statusJSON.push(status);

      Write("<br>" + Stringify(statusJSON).replace(/\{/g,",<br>"));

  }
}
massUpsert(subObj1,allSubscribers);
</script>
```

**Output**

```
[,
"SubscriberKey":"16347460029","EmailAddress":"email1@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}]
[,
"SubscriberKey":"16347460029","EmailAddress":"email1@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"345383714258","EmailAddress":"email2@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}]
[,
"SubscriberKey":"16347460029","EmailAddress":"email1@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"345383714258","EmailAddress":"email2@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"44568799855","EmailAddress":"email3@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}]
[,
"SubscriberKey":"16347460029","EmailAddress":"email1@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"345383714258","EmailAddress":"email2@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"44568799855","EmailAddress":"email3@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"43658751542","EmailAddress":"email4@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}]
[,
"SubscriberKey":"16347460029","EmailAddress":"email1@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"345383714258","EmailAddress":"email2@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"44568799855","EmailAddress":"email3@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"43658751542","EmailAddress":"email4@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}, ,
"SubscriberKey":"77836423975","EmailAddress":"email5@gmail.com","UpsertStatus":"OK"}]
```

Comment: Thank you Adam!  That was exactly my problem, I must be rusty today from my 2 weeks PTO :)

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work in a child BU.  Do I need to do anything different?